# Understanding of dot with text in square brackets in manpage

Tags: man

In some man pages, e.g. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memchr.3.html, I see the following:

```
       void *memchr(const void s[.n], int c, size_t n);
```

e.g. on https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bsearch.3.html,

```
  void *bsearch(const void key[.size], const void base[.size * .nmemb],
                     size_t nmemb, size_t size,
                     int (*compar)(const void [.size], const void [.size]));
```

What is the significance or interpretation of the `[.n]` ,  `[.nmemb]`, and `[.size]` term? What is the dot meaning also?

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77709310/man-pages-convention-squarebracket-annotation-in-c-function-prototypes which is answered by previous https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77035306/linux-memcpy-restrict-keyword-syntax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They represent the size of the arrays, or of the object pointed to (or a combination). For example, in

```c
void *memchr(const void s[.n], int c, size_t n);
```

`s` would historically be written `const void * s`, and points to an array of `n` bytes (or more). The [commit introducing this notation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/commit/?id=c64cd13e002561c6802c6a1a1a8a640f034fea70) refers to VLA syntax, although in C99 [the corresponding syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array) doesn’t use a leading dot and requires the size parameter to be declared before its use (and as far as I’m aware, isn’t valid for `void *`).

A valid example of this type of syntax is

```c
int main(int argc, char * argv[argc + 1]);
```

The `bsearch` declaration is more complex: `key` points to a single object of size `size`, `base` points to an array of `nmemb` elements each of size `size`, and the `compar` function is called with pointers to objects of size `size`.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation continues

> The `memchr()` function scans the initial n bytes of the memory area pointed to by s for the first instance of c.

So what it's telling you is that `n` bytes from the location pointed at by `s` are considered